# Open Graph - Facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use Open Graph tags to share the site. On the desktop does't have problem, but if I use a mobile device is not working properly. Do not take my description and picture. Anyone had any similar problem? How to become equally to both (mobile and desktop) ?

Here is my OG meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MyWebSite" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My web site" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My description !" />
```

Comment: Currently I have the same issue, have you come across anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?fbrefresh=ANY_RANDOM_NUMBER` after your URL.

Like this :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com?fbrefresh=9999" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use link for og:url not a meta tag
`<link property:"og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com?fbrefresh=9999">`